# Twilio-node VoiceResponse error when returning twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I've written a twilio-function that spits out a bit of twiml to read out the users current weather. However somewhere outside my code the twiml generation fails.

https://gist.github.com/machinshin/331efc2ab31277b98fcb343704d711e9

the relevant bits of code are lines 77-79.

the console.log at line 77 dumps the following to stdin:

```
    twiml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Say voice="Polly.Joanna">Hi</Say><Say voice="Polly.Joanna">According to OpenWeatherMap the station nearest Berkeley is currently scattered clouds
          with a temperature ranging from 57.6 Fahrenheit to 60.01 degrees Fahrenheit and a relative humidity of
          43% with an average wind speed of: 5.82 miles per hour</Say></Response>
```

Then the framework dumps a XML conversion error of this, but as far as I can tell I'm doing everything correct, any help/thoughts?

```
(node:20051) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'XMLDocument'
    |     property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'XMLDeclaration'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/vat/.twilio-cli/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/vat/.twilio-cli/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/vat/.twilio-cli/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at handleSuccess (/Users/vat/.twilio-cli/node_modules/twilio-run/dist/runtime/route.js:116:9)
    at callback (/Users/vat/.twilio-cli/node_modules/twilio-run/dist/runtime/route.js:164:13)
    at exports.handler (/Users/vat/workspace/machinshin/projects/idwresearch/dist/functions/get_say_weather.protected.js:71:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:20051) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20051) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me without error:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

const jsLog = (obj) => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

const voice = 'Polly.Joanna';
const OW_URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

async function getWeatherForZipcode(OW_APP_ID, zipcode, countryCode, units) {
  const zip = `${zipcode},${countryCode}`.toLowerCase().trim();
  return axios
    .get(OW_URL, {
      params: {
        appid: OW_APP_ID,
        units: units || 'imperial',
        zip,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`getWeatherForZipcode: error: ${jsLog(err)}`);
      throw new Error(err);
    });
}

/** parseWeatherResponse
 * @param
 *
 **/
function parseWeatherResponse(data) {
  return {
    current_conditions: data.weather[0].description,
    station_at: data.name,
    temp: data.main.temp,
    temp_max: data.main.temp_max,
    humidity: data.main.humidity,
    wind_speed: data.wind.speed,
  };
}

/** handler
 *  @param {Context} context
 *  @param {Event} event
 *  @param {ServerlessCallback} callback
 *  @returns {twiml.VoiceResponse}
 **/

exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  try {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    console.log(`-------------------\n`);
    const OW_APP_ID = context.OW_APP_ID;
    const { units, zip, countryCode } = event;
    const z = zip.toLowerCase().trim();
    const cc = countryCode.toLowerCase().trim();
    const uu = units.toLowerCase().trim();

    const response = await getWeatherForZipcode(OW_APP_ID, z, cc, uu);
    const toSay = parseWeatherResponse(response);

    // const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    const say = twiml.say({ voice: 'Polly.Joanna' }, 'Hi');

    twiml.say(
      { voice },
      `According to OpenWeatherMap the station nearest ${toSay.station_at} is currently ${toSay.current_conditions}
    with a temperature ranging from ${toSay.temp} Fahrenheit to ${toSay.temp_max} degrees Fahrenheit and a relative humidity of
    ${toSay.humidity}% with an average wind speed of: ${toSay.wind_speed} miles per hour`,
    );

    console.log(`twiml: ${twiml.toString()}`);

    return callback(null, twiml);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
    console.log(`some error was thrown: ${jsLog(err)}`);
    return callback(`err: ${jsLog(err)}, event: ${jsLog(event)}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the difference.. you removed the "require('twilio')", so how the code is using 'built-in' library version.. I wonder what the differences in behavior are..

Comment: You can change the built in Twilio Helper library by updating the dependency in the Twilio Function (under Dependencies for Functions V2) to point to a newer version, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/CHANGES.md. You can instantiate the built in library using: `const client = context.getTwilioClient();`, and no need to require it.

Comment: Ps. Nice code, very organized and easy to follow :)